# Classifying map for the hyperplane bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ be a topological group and $X$ be a CW complex. Then principal $G$-bundles on $X$ is classified by the [classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) $BG$ in the sense that, given a principal $G$-bundle $P \to X$, there is a continuous map $f\colon X \to BG$ such that $P = f^* EG$, where $EG$ is a contractible space on which $G$ acts freely with quotient $BG$. In the case when $G = S^1$, it is known that $BG = \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$.

If we state this in terms of [associated comlex line bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_bundle) with the standard $S^1$-action on $\mathbb{C}$, given a complex line bundle $L \to X$, there is a map $f\colon X \to \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ such that $L$ is the pullback of the universal line bundle by $f$.

When $X = \mathbb{C}P^n$, there are two important line bundles on $X$. The first one is the [tautological line bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_bundle), usually denoted by $\mathcal{O}(-1)$, which is defined to be the bundle whose fiber at $\ell \in \mathbb{C}P^n$ consists of points on $\ell$ considered as a line in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. In this case, the classifying map $f\colon \mathbb{C}P^n \to \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ is the natural inclusion. The other one is the hyperplane bundle, the dual bundle of the tautological one. My question is

> What is the classifying map for the hyperplane bundle $\mathcal{O}(1) \to \mathbb{C}P^n$? More generally, can we find the classifying map for $\mathcal{O}(k)$ for each $k$?

If this is difficult or complicated, the formula for $n=1$ or any reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coordinates change of a line bundle is $u_{ij}$, the coordinate change of the dual are $u_{tij}^{-1}$, for $n=1$, the map of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ induced by $(z_1,z_2)\rightarrow (\bar z_1,\bar z_2)$ change $O(1)$ to $O(-1)$. Just see how it acts on the coordinates change.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see how to do this. By the way, your answer seems incorrect. The map switching the coordinates is holomorphic, hence of degree one. Maybe we should take conjugation.

Answer (score 1):

For $k > 0$, $\mathcal{O}(k) \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ is very ample, so there is an embedding $\varphi : \mathbb{CP}^n \to \mathbb{CP}^N$ such that $\varphi^*\mathcal{O}(1) \cong \mathcal{O}(k)$ (and hence $\varphi^*\mathcal{O}(-1) \cong \mathcal{O}(-k)$).

As the other answer alludes to, complex conjugation $c : \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ induces a map $c : \mathbb{CP}^n \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ and if $E$ is a complex vector bundle, $c^*E \cong \overline{E}\cong E^*$, so $c^*\mathcal{O}(-k) \cong \mathcal{O}(k)$.

Let $i$ denote the inclusion $\mathbb{CP}^N \hookrightarrow \mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$. Combining the two facts above, we see that $i\circ\varphi$ is a classifying map for $\mathcal{O}(-k) \to \mathbb{CP}^n$, and $i\circ c\circ \varphi$ is a classifying map for $\mathcal{O}(k) \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ (as is $i\circ\varphi\circ c$).

Comment: Nice answer. To get the rest, precompose with complex conjugation.