# How do I view the tangent bundle of 2-sphere as pullback from the universal bundle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, grassmannian, classifying-spaces

I am trying to visualize that any vector bundle is a pullback from the Tautological bundle of Grassmannian.

If the tangent bundle of $S^2$ is not a simple example, is there a/the simplest example? The tangent bundle of torus $T^2$ is a trivial bundle so that doesn't count.

Comment: The simplest example is the tautological bundle over projective space because the pullback is just the restriction of the universal bundle along the inclusion. You can try to write what it is for $TS^2$ using clutching functions and the loops suspension adjunction, but I don't know if it is really "visualizable".

Comment: There are explicit classifying maps for $\mathcal{O}(k) \to \mathbb{CP}^n$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2986942/39599). The case of the tangent bundle of $S^2$ is $k = 2$ and $n = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vector bundles over manifolds there is a particularly simple construction, it goes as follows in your example. Embed $TS^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbf{R}^n \hookrightarrow\mathbf{R}^\infty$ (for instance by embedding $S^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbf{R}^k$ and getting $TS^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbf{R}^{2k}$) and map $x \in S^2$ to $T_xS^2 \in \mathrm{Gr}(2, n) \subset \mathrm{Gr}(2, \infty)$. Since different embeddings are isotopic (in $\mathbf{R}^\infty$), this map does not depend, upto homotopy, on the choice of embedding.

In the case of the tangent bundle, obtained by embedding the underlying manifold, this is often called the [Gauss map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map).

Comment: A few questions: (1) For $S^2$ what would be $n$ and $k$? (2) Why would $S^2$ and $TS^2$ be embedded in some finite-dimensional Euclidean then in infinite $\mathbf{R}^\infty$, why not directly in $\mathbf{R}^\infty$? (3) $S^2$ can be embedded in $R^3$ and am I right that $TS^2$ is isomorphic to $G(2,3)$?

Comment: *correction: $TS^2$ is not isomorphic to $G(2,3)$. But I can pullback $G(2,3)$ to $S^2$ quite easily, it is a 2:1 map. Am I right?

Comment: @Alex You can directly embed in $\mathbf{R}^\infty$ if you like, it doesn't change anything but makes it harder to visualize maybe. For $S^2$ you can take the standard embedding $k = 3$, and then in fact you get a map to $G(2, 3)$ by projecting to $0 \times \mathbf{R}^3$. The point is to realize $x \mapsto T_x S^2$ as a map to $G(n, \infty)$, the details of the embedding do not matter up to homotopy.